# In a calendar app, is there any reason force both start and end times as opposed to having an optional end time?

Tags: calendar

If I have an event with an unknown/variable end time, such as a dinner party or dentist appointment, I would assume it makes most sense to not put in an end time at all for that event.

But is this case too unique to cover? Are there any disadvantages to allowing this? Most calendar apps don't allow a single time event, and I am wondering why that is.

Answer (score 4):

Without end times, there's the risk of not being able to warn the user about overlapping appointments.

Let's say you enter a 6pm dinner party into your calendar with no end time. What happens when you receive an invite to go see at movie at 8pm? Will the app know that there's a conflict, and be able to warn you?

Comment: One common compromise is to have a default and/or one-button duration option. Business scheduling systems often assume 1-hour duration unless told otherwise. Personal systems might let the user pick a default but make it easy to override. Note that for many things, duration is more convenient than end time... but not for all.